# Exit a tkinter window even when unfocused

Tags: python, tkinter, focus

I am making an AI that beats the game Whac-A-Mole. This program takes over the mouse and therefore I need to make a way to stop the program from running (you can barely move the mouse, so pressing a button in Tkinter won't work). I settled on the 'Escape' key as the switch to turn it off. The problem is, whenever the AI whacks a mole (clicks on the screen), the Tkinter window becomes unfocused, therefore 'bind' doesn't work.

Is there a way of stopping the program without the Tkinter window being focused?

Comment: This description is too vague to elicit a useful response. Please try to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you want the window to focus, you can use the `.focus()` method.

For example:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window2 = Toplevel()
window.mainloop()
```

The second window, `window2` won't be in focus. To put it in focus, you can do this:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("window1")
window2 = Toplevel()
window2.title("window2")
window2.focus()
window.mainloop()
```

This will bring the window2 into focus, even though on the bottom.

To bring it to the top, you can add this line:

```py
window2.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To bring the tkinter window on the top all other window you can use :

```
from tkinter import*
gui = Tk()
gui.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
gui.mainloop()
```